# Push pointers to vector at runtime C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

My program will read input data that contains N lines. Each line contains data that will be assigned to a single object. Since the number of objects required will be determined at runtime, I plan to allocate space for them on the heap.

I want to include a vector of pointers to these objects. My first approach was to use a loop running N times, and allocate the space with,

`Customer* cust_i = new Customer`

Then use `customer_vector.push_back(cust_i)` to populate the vector.

Seems clumsy, and given that I don't understand dynamic memory allocation in C++ all that well, I would appreciate any advice approaching this problem a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered `vector<Customer>` rather than `vector<Customer*>`?

Comment: What is the reason for the pointer usage?  Why not simply `std::vector<Customer> customer_vector;` and then `customer_vector.push_back(Customer());`?  No pointer usage at all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Along with the accepted answer below, this has helped me understand the vector data structure a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to store the pointers to `Customer` 
Since vector is already a dynamic container you can do

```
std::vector<Customer> customer_vec;

// read file
// ...
// example assuming Customer has a constructor taking 2 strings
customer_vec.emplace_back( "foo", "bar" );
```